# Filling up the remaining row spaces in html

Tags: html

I want the blocks at the very top when you run this HTML file to spread so that it can cover the spaces available on its row. I tried inserting `justify-content: space-between;` inside the `.title li` but it didn't work. please tell me what is my code missing. Also if it's ok can you please tell me what color combinations would be good for the font and its background? thank you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Names -->
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Block and Inline Flow </title>

            <style type = "text/css">
            .title li {
            display: inline;
            background-color: papayawhip;
            border: double;
            border-color: blue red green yellow;
            margin: 2px;
            padding: .5em;
            }
            </style>
            
            <style type = "text/css">
            .student1 li {
            display: block;
            background-color:#000000;
            border: none;
            border-color: none;
            margin: 2px;
            padding: .5em;
            }
            </style>

            <style type = "text/css">
            .student2 li {
            display: block;
            background-color:#000080;
            border: none;
            border-color: none;
            margin: 2px;
            padding: .5em;
            }
            </style>
    </head>
<body>

    <h1> Student Information: </h1>
        <ul class = "title li">
            <li>Name</li>
            <li>Date of Birth</li>
            <li>Home Address</li>
            <li>E-mail Address</li>
            <li>School</li>
            <li>School Address</li>
        </ul>
        
        <ul class = "student1 li">
        <font color=grey> 
            <li>Name: ******** </li>
            <li>Date of Birth: ********</li>
            <li>Home Address: ********</li>
            <li>E-mail Address: ********</li>
            <li>School: ********</li>
            <li>School Address: ********</li>
        </font> 
        </ul>
        
        <ul class = "student2 li">
        <font color=gold> 
            <li>Name: ******** </li>
            <li>Date of Birth: ********</li>
            <li>Home Address: ********</li>
            <li>E-mail Address: ********</li>
            <li>School: ********</li>
            <li>School Address: ********</li>
        </font>
        </ul>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `display: flex` in order to use `justify-content: space-between`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Names -->
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Block and Inline Flow </title>

            <style>
            .title{
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: row;
                justify-content: space-between;
                list-style-type: none;
             }
            .title li {
  
            background-color: grey;
            border: double;
            border-color: blue;
            margin: 2px;
            padding: .5em;
            }
            </style>
            
            <style>
            .student1 li {
            display: block;
            background-color:#000000;
            border: none;
            border-color: none;
            margin: 2px;
            padding: .5em;
            }
            </style>

            <style type = "text/css">
            .student2 li {
            display: block;
            background-color:#000080;
            border: none;
            border-color: none;
            margin: 2px;
            padding: .5em;
            }
            </style>
    </head>
<body>

    <h1> Student Information: </h1>
        <ul class = "title li">
            <li>Name</li>
            <li>Date of Birth</li>
            <li>Home Address</li>
            <li>E-mail Address</li>
            <li>School</li>
            <li>School Address</li>
        </ul>
        
        <ul class = "student1 li">
        <font color=grey> 
            <li>Name: ******** </li>
            <li>Date of Birth: ********</li>
            <li>Home Address: ********</li>
            <li>E-mail Address: ********</li>
            <li>School: ********</li>
            <li>School Address: ********</li>
        </font> 
        </ul>
        
        <ul class = "student2 li">
        <font color=gold> 
            <li>Name: ******** </li>
            <li>Date of Birth: ********</li>
            <li>Home Address: ********</li>
            <li>E-mail Address: ********</li>
            <li>School: ********</li>
            <li>School Address: ********</li>
        </font>
        </ul>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried running your code it did fill up the spaces but how do I remove the bullets before each block?

Comment: nvm i already fixed it I just added `display: inline;` inside `.title li`

Comment: just put `list-style-type: none;` in styles of `ul`, I've edited my answer accordingly.